# Difference between comment_count and commentsbox_count

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

In the API result (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) there are two counts about comments:

**comment_count**: The number of comments users have made on the shared story
**commentsbox_count**: The number of comments from a comments box on this URL. This only includes top level comments, not replies

What is the difference?  Does the comment_count include the commentsbox_count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are quite different from each other. 
comment_count refers to the number of comments made inside Facebook on a shared story, where as commentsbox_count refers to the comments made on the external site via the comments plugin. 
Sites can use the comments plugin to easily put up a comment box on their website without having to implement it themselves. The commentsbox_count can be queried to get the # of comments left on each URL there.

Comment: Does that mean that the comment_count does NOT include the commentsbox_count?

Comment: Yes, I believe they are independent. The commentsbox_count is exclusively the number of comments received directly on the URL via the comments plugin.